# Reference the form in a function of a class

Tags: c#

Here is my code for a `CheckXWinner` function, where I need to reference my Form in order to draw win lines:

```
    public void CheckXWinner(Button[] buttonArray, Form1 frm)
    {
        int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
        int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));
        bool winner = false;//variable to keep the computer from going when Xwins
        for (int i = 0;  i < root;  i++)
        {
            //Sets the counter for the winners back to zero
            int d2Count = 0;
            int d1Count = 0;
            int hCount = 0;
            int vCount = 0;

                for(int j = 0;  j < root; j++)
                {
                    //increments the appropriate counter if the button contains an X
                    //Horizonal win
                    if (buttonArray[(i*root) + j].Text == "X")
                    {
                        hCount++;
                        if (hCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(i*root) + z].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; //sets winner to true so computer does not take turn 
                        }
                    }//end of Horizonal win

                    //Left to right diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[j + (j*root)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d1Count++;
                        if (d1Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[z + (z * root)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of LTR win

                    //Right to left diagonal
                    if (buttonArray[(j*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        d2Count++;
                        if (d2Count == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[(z*(root - 1)) + (root - 1)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of RTL win

                    //Vertical win
                    if (buttonArray[i + (root*j)].Text == "X")
                    {
                        vCount++;
                        if (vCount == root)
                        {
                            for (int z = (root - 1); z >= 0; z--)
                            {
                                buttonArray[i + (root*z)].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                            }
                            Xwins();
                            winner = true; 
                        }
                    }//end of vert win                        
                }//end of for j loop
        }//end of for loop
        CheckDraw();
        if (winner == false)
        {
            ComputerGoes(buttonArray);
        };

    }//end of CheckXWinner
```

In another part of this class I have the handler for all button clicks associated with the form:

```
    //Handle any button clicks
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Text = "X";
        b.Enabled = false;
        CheckXWinner(buttonArray, Form1 frm);
    }
```

I have errors for the Form1 part of that call, how do I fix this???

Comment: ***What*** Are The Errors?!?

Comment: In which Form are you handling that button click?

Comment: I have a Gameboard Class that this is all in, separate from the Form. The button click is outside of the constructor in the Gameboard class so is CheckXWinner and so on

Answer (score 1):

Where you are passing `Form1 frm` you should actually pass a reference to an instance on Form1. Based on your comment to the suggestion of passing `this` it seems that the button handler is declared inside another form (not in Form1). If that's the case you should obtain/keep a reference to a Form1 instance and pass that in:

```
CheckXWinner(buttonArray, a_ref_to_form);
```

However, looking at your implementation of `CheckXWinner` it doesn't look like you are referencing `frm` anywhere anyway!

Rewrite the declaration of CheckXWinner as

```
public void CheckXWinner(Button[] buttonArray)
```

And call it like this:

```
CheckXWinner(buttonArray);
```

Comment: yeah its in there so I can reference it in drawing a winline (havent written that part yet)

Comment: please see my comment below, I tried passing in 'this' and I get an error. I had tried this prior to posting and thats why I am confused as to what Im doing wrong here

Comment: I am passing the Form reference because I need to reference it in the function for drawing dynamic winlines. For the code I need to reference the form as the canvas etc. I havent written that code yet, I just noticed that I wasnt getting a clean build and cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

frm isn't declared anywhere when you pass it as a parameter.

pass "this" instead of Form1 frm.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for CheckXWinner(System.Windows.Forms.Button[], MyProgram.Form1) has some invalid arguments

Comment: instead of buttonarray try passing "b".

Comment: The function worked fine when all I was passing in was buttonarray, and not involving the form reference in the function definition. After I added the Form reference to the definition, the function gives me errors when I try to call it